# The partial derivatives position

Tags: partial-derivative

Is $\displaystyle \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \ x=x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}=1$?

Comment: $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}x=\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}=1$. However $x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}=1$ has no sense, it is a derivative of what?

Comment: I'm calculating laplacian where I should express a coordinate system in terms of a and b (check my recently post)  and I got $\displaystyle \frac{\partial}{\partial a} a$ which is equal to 1. OK. BUT, then I also got  $\displaystyle a\frac{\partial}{\partial a}$ is it also equal to one????

Comment: you should clarify in your post that the "1" is not a number but the identity operator, ie $1:f(x)\to f(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. In the way you wrote, they should be intended as operator acting on something.
So the first one is
$$
\partial_x(xu) = u + x\partial_x u
$$
while the second is
$$
x\partial_x u.
$$
Note so that $\partial_x x - x \partial_x = 1$, as operators acting on something.

Comment: Ok dude thanks!! So they are not EQUAL?

Comment: No, since their difference is 1 (always, intended as multiplication operators).

Comment: The "No", is sus for me :/. So a better question: Are they equal? Yes or No :D, Sorry for my bad english

Comment: See above please.

Comment: No. They are not equal. More precisely, it depends on the context, I'm intending them as multiplication operators. Example: consider the $\partial_x$ operator, then $\partial_x x =1$, but clearly the derivative operator is not equal to 1.

Comment: Okay! Thank you so much Angelo!

Comment: If you are computing the laplacian, I think $\partial_a a$ is not 1, but is an operator that act on something, so it is $\partial_a(a u) = u + a\partial_a u$, that is $\partial_ a a = a\partial_a + 1$.

Comment: check this please, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4330190/express-the-laplacian-partial2-x-partial2-y-in-terms-of-the-coordinate?noredirect=1#comment9031688_4330190

Comment: See above please